# R as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) returns date a day early

Tags: r, time, posixct

What am I missing ?

```
Sys.Date()
[1] "2011-12-15"

as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
[1] "2011-12-14 19:00:00 EST"  # Returning the day before !!

as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
[1] "2011-12-14 19:00:00 EST"  # Still returning day before !!

Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;
LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Its likely a time zone problem.  Try this:

```
as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date()))
```

Note that `Sys.time()` also exists.

See R Help Desk article in [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) for some details on this.

Comment: To elaborate a tiny bit more, do what @BenBolker said, and then try `methods(as.POSIXct)`, and type first `as.POSIXct.Date` and then `as.POSIXct.default` at the command line.

Comment: Its 5 hours before midnight - ie the offset between GMT and EST.